# Azure Application Insights continuous export using powershell fails

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights, azure-powershell

I am running the below command on cloud shell of App Insights resource:

My App Insights instance is in pme tenant and storage account is in corp tenant. I have granted access to AI instance for Read/Write/Add/Create in blob container using sasURI

Below is the export command I use

```
New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport -ResourceGroupName "<rgname>" -Name "<ainame>" -DocumentType "Request","Dependency","Custom Event" -StorageAccountId "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<blobstoragename>" -StorageLocation southcentralus  -StorageSASUri "<sasUri" -debug
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
DEBUG: ResponseCreated: 
DEBUG: [Finally]: Cannot deserialize due to Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
DEBUG: [Finally]: Getting exception 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Exceptions.AzPSCloudException: InternalException' from response
DEBUG: Finally: 
New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport_CreateExpanded: /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/Az.ApplicationInsights/2.2.2/custom/New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport.ps1:161
Line |
 161 |          . Az.ApplicationInsights.internal\New-AzApplicationInsightsCo …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The server responded with a Request Error, Status: BadRequest
```

Not sure what is wrong with the command.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the access between the Azure AD tenants (pme/corp tenants) has been properly configured and allowed. And also, you can check that the App Insights instance has the required permissions to access the storage account in a different tenant.

Refer this MS Doc for [cross-tenant access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/cross-tenant-access-overview).

Usually, bad request error comes when the parameters in the command are not properly given. Check the `storage account ID` whether you are correctly given. Generate the `sasuri` correctly and make sure that you have the necessary permissions to access the storage account blob as well.

*I tried the same requirement in my environment and it worked for me as follows.*

Before exporting the Application insights, set the storage account context using `New-AzstorageContext` command properly.

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName <storaegeaccountName> -StorageAccountKey "<storageKey==>"
```

Once it is done, you can generate the `sastoken, sasuri` and then proceed for the exporting insights as shown:

```
$SAStoken = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Name <containername> -Context $context -Permission w -Context $context
$SASuri = "bloburi" + $SAStoken
New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport -ResourceGroupName "<Resourcegroup>" -Name "<Applicationinsightname>" -DocumentType "Request","Trace" -StorageAccountId "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccountname>" -StorageLocation "EastUS" -StorageSASUri $SASuri -DestinationType Blob
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Refer [New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/new-azapplicationinsightscontinuousexport?view=azps-10.0.0) for better understanding.